# How to continuously keep watch on our local server say ' http://localhost:8080/app ' whether its live or dead by using another Node.js server

Tags: node.js

We have two Node.js servers. First one is running on http://localhost:8080/. Second server wants to keep watch on first server continuosly like 'if running then console.log('live') else console.log('dead')'. If we use setInterval, it will do the same but we get repeated messages 'live' or 'dead'. Actually we can write a complex logic in setInterval to avoid this issue, but don't want to do that. Thanks you in advance.

Comment: " If we use setInterval, it will do the same but we get repeated messages 'live' or 'dead'". What does this really mean? Don't you want the other server to check if your main site is live?

Comment: I mean I want to use Events.

Comment: I don't think I entirely understand what you mean. Could you post something you've tried? Also, why can't you just probe the server every few minutes?

Comment: Hi Zeokav, this is what I tried.

 var express = require('express') 
 var request = require('request') 
 const app = express() 
 
 setInterval(function(){
 request.get('localhost:3003/') 
 .on('response', function(response) { 
  console.log('Connected'); 
  }) 
 .on('error', function(err) {
  console.log('Disconneted') 
  }) 
},5000); 


Result :

Connected
Connected
Connected
Connected
Connected
Connected
Connected
Connected
Connected
Connected
Connected
Connected
Connected
Connected
Connected
Connected
Connected
Connected
Connected
Connected
Connected

Comment: I dont want these repeated console logs, instead of this I just want to get notified whenever state changes.

Answer (score 0):

Will this do the trick?

```
const request = require('request');

let lastState = '';

function checkState(newState) {
  if (newState !== lastState) {
    console.log(newState);
    lastState = newState;
  }
}

setInterval(function() {
  request
    .get('localhost:3003/')
    .on('response', function(response) {
      checkState('Connected');
    })
    .on('error', function(err) {
      checkState('Disconneted');
    })
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Yes thank you @vsenko. But the problem I am facing now is - I am getting first few messages on console correctly and on time as I turn my first server on or off. But "After sometime  Connected / Disconnected messages are not coming on time due to Asynchronous Behavior. As I turn off second server by pressing ctrl+c that remaining messages get printed on console".

Comment: Yes, this approach will not work very well if the monitored service is flapping. I think that the main reason is the timeout during which `request` waits for response from the server. You can try to lower the `timeout` option (https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback) to mitigate this effect.

Comment: Another option is to cease reacting on `error` events and to implement timeout by yourself and then consider service *Disconnected* if timeout reaches earlier than `response` from your monitored server.